# Python function (or set of functions) as input of a function or class

Tags: python

is there a way of having an (yet unkown) function as an argument of a function in python:

```
def doSomething(<func>):
    #do something with func()
```

at a later stage, functions could be defined, eg:

```
def f1(x):
    return x*x

def f2(x):
    return x+1
```

and I could call now:

```
doSomething(f1,x1)
doSomething(f2,x1)
```

Comment: why the downvote ?

Comment: Yes. What happened when you tried?

Comment: @Newtopian: lack of effort, and it should be on Stack Overflow. Scribbled a short answer anyway because why not, but it's not a good question for here.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich thanks, indeed better for SO, it has in fact already been answered there :-)  I was asking mostly for the OP`s sake, I find rude to downvote without (stating) reason, else how are we to correct innapropriate questions if we are not told what is wrong with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are perfectly normal objects in Python, so the answer is yes.

```
def callFunctionTwice(func, arg):
    func(arg)
    func(arg)

def f(a):
    print(a)

callFunctionTwice(f, "hmm")  # Prints "hmm" twice
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292239/python-functions-are-objects) better than I could at Stack Overflow, be sure to upvote his answer in addition (or instead of) my own if satisfactory.

but for completeness here are the takeaways :

- define your own class and overload the **call** method
- function object have it naturally, just call it to invoke the function
- Lambda expressions can also get the desired effect